# Origin of Min/Max values fed to tickPositioner - bug?

Tags: highcharts

I noticed that min/max values that are fed to a custom tickPositioner function are not the same as min/max values of the data set. For example, my max value when chart is downloaded as CSV is 353116.2853, but max value provided to the tickPositioner is 390819.334993875.

Similarly, min value in the dataset is -400944.7087, but tickPositioner receives 
-438647.758392375.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Could you please provide your code's fiddle so that people here may investigate the issue properly.

Comment: In the tickPosiitoner you can refer to this.dataMin / this.dataMax instead of min/max on axis.

Comment: Those values are the axis min/max, not the data min/max